# Multipass Source path does not exist

Tags: mount, multipass

I'm running multipass on Ubuntu Desktop 21.04 to create many Ubuntu VMs on this Ubuntu machine. I need to mount a folder I created at the root directory `/app` to one of the VMs. While `ls -l /app` shows the folder, `multipass mount /app newvm` gives the error that `Source path "/app" does not exist`.

If I try to use autocomplete with `multipass mount /` and press tab it shows most of the folders in my root directory but not the `/app` folder.

For testing, I created a new root level folder using `sudo mkdir /bob`. Then `multipass mount /bob newvm`. Still same error. `Source path "/bob" does not exist`

Why would multipass not show all the root level folders?

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  No such release, so do you mean Ubuntu Core 20?  (Ubuntu uses *year.month* for *deb* based products & the *year* format for *snap* only products)

Comment: Actually it is Ubuntu Desktop 21 (21.04). I started with Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.2.0, but recently upgraded. I've updated the post with that version number, if it matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If Multipass was installed the 'default' way `snap install multipass`, it won't be able to access directories outside of your /home, /mnt, or /media because of its strict confinement policy. Classic snaps, installs using the `--classic` parameter, don't have this restriction and have much greater access to the system as they aren't tightly sandboxed.

A little more on [confinement policies](https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-to-snap-introducing-classic-confinement).

If it's not convenient to move the /app directory to /mnt or /media (and I assume its not convenient to put it in your /home), you can try installing multipass with `snap install multipass --classic`

Interesting to note the video on the snap store page uses the `--classic` flag in the demo, but the install button does not include it.

Comment: Thanks. More confinement is important for me, so I will move /app inside of /mnt. It’s inconvenient but doable.